# Can different sessions of the same linux user have different local repos for the same public repo?

Tags: linux, git

We have a program with only one license on a linux machine, so we have to work with different sessions of the same user.
Is it still possible to have 2 working local repositories on that machine that push and pull to/from the same public repo?

Could there be any workaround to make that work?

Comment: Clone the remote repo to two different locations. Git is not centralised, so you can have as many local "copies" as you like.

Comment: Also, consider using `git worktree` to save yourself some effort. It's not clear whether the restrictions that `git worktree` adds would be any issue for you, but if not, it saves you disk usage and makes new commits in each worktree accessible from the other working tree (but not part of it, just view-able, cherry-pick-able, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything about a git repository in Linux is stored remotely in the repository's directory, inside the hidden directory `.git`

This means you can have two directories that are repositories with their own history that can push/pull/fetch/etc without affecting the other one.

Let's say you have a public GitHub repository. You could create two directories:

`mkdir workingDirOne`

`mkdir workingDirTwo`

Then, clone the public repository into each one

`cd workingDirOne`

`git clone (GitHub URL)`

`cd ..`

`cd workingDirTwo`

`git clone (GitHub URL)`

In this case, both `workingDirOne` and `workingDirTwo` will have their own versions of the repository. Now two instances of the same user could modify one without affecting the other.